# Exception in a release build only

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2013, mfc, release

I'm working on a big solution that includes more than 40 projects. Some changes to the solution made the release build unstable - it throws the `Access violation reading location` exception (but everything is ok under debug). After a lot of investigation I localized the issue but that didn't give me a clue of how to solve it.

I uploaded the [sample project](https://github.com/do-that/TestApp) to github. It contains the minimal amount of data needed to reproduce the issue. It consists from a 3 projects: `App` - an executable, `TestLib` and `TestLib.Data` - static libraries.

**TestLib.Data:**

```
// stdafx.h
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#include <afxwin.h>

//--------------------

// SomeData.h
#pragma once
class CSomeData
{
public:
    CSomeData();
    CSomeData(const CSomeData &cSomeData);
private:
    GUID m_Guid;
};

//--------------------

// SomeData.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SomeData.h"

CSomeData::CSomeData() {}
CSomeData::CSomeData(const CSomeData &cSomeData) {}
```

**TestLib:**

```
// stdafx.h
#pragma once
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#include "targetver.h"
#include <afxwin.h>

//--------------------

// SomeClass.h
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include "..\TestLib.Data\SomeData.h"

class CSomeClass
{
public:
    CSomeClass();
    void doWork();
    std::map<int, CSomeData> m_map;
};

//--------------------

// SomeClass.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CSomeClass.h"

CSomeClass::CSomeClass() {}

void CSomeClass::doWork()
{
    for (std::pair<int, CSomeData> p : m_map)
    {
    }
}
```

**App**

It literally contains the auto-generated code for the MFC multi-document application. The only things added to `MyApp` class implementation are:

```
#include "..\TestLib\CSomeClass.h"

//...

BOOL MyApp::InitInstance() 
{
     //...

    CSomeClass sc;
    sc.doWork();

    return TRUE;
}
```

All projects are using the `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)` platform toolset.

Running under `Release|x86` ends in an `Access violation` exception.

Can anyone please explain me what's wrong here?

**EDIT**

The exception and the call stack:
[image: The exception and the call stack]

**EDIT 2**

The ways to fix the issue:

- remove the `for` loop from `CSomeClass::doWork()`
- remove the copy constructor from `CSomeData` class
- remove the `#include <afxwin.h>` from `stdafx.h` in `TestLib.Data`
- remove `/clr` support

Neither of this I can use as a solution. The question is - why such changes prevents the exception?

Comment: You should include the code to reproduce the problem into the question itself instead of giving link to somewhere (though additional link to online compiler would be good). You clearly have an UB or some other programming error somewhere. The code you've posted right now seems ok, except that it would be better to reqrite `for (std::pair<int, CSomeData> p : m_map)` as `for (std::pair<int, CSomeData> & p : m_map)` so it won't copy anything.

Comment: Where is the exception raised? What's the callstack at the point of failure? Attach a debugger to find that out. See [How to: Debug Optimized Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-optimized-code) if necessary.

Comment: @IInspectable Exception and call stack is attached

Comment: @VTT is that a valid syntax? I tried and get `Error C2440 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' to 'std::pair<int,CSomeData> &'`

Comment: Right, map value type has const-qualified key, so it should be `for (std::pair<int const, CSomeData> & p : m_map)`, or even `for (auto & p : m_map)`. But my primary point was to avoid copying of objects. Now the exception call stack does not match the given code at all... You should post real code here.

Comment: @VTT as I see - copying is a key issue here. If I remove the `for` loop - I will not get the exception. The thing is - I need the copying. And I can't understand why copying produces the exception.

Comment: If that indeed is the location of the exception, then that means `pThread` is null. That means your application failed to properly initialize. You don't even get to the point of copying things around; it fails long before that.

Comment: @IInspectable you are right. But how can I found where the issue lies?

Comment: By producing a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable well, I did produce it. I added a link to github with such project. The thing is - without any of the `TestLib` projects or without changes in `App` project everything works well.

Comment: Few more things: removing the `for` loop in `CSomeClass::doWork()` or removing copy constructor in `CSomeData` class or removing `#include <afxwin.h>` from `TestLib.Data` fixes the issue. This is not a solution for me. The question is still - why it fixes?

Comment: Presumably, those libraries are static libraries. They shouldn't be linking with MFC. Are they?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176786/discussion-between-sergey-shevchenko-and-iinspectable).

Comment: *"I added a link to github with such project."* You should instead provide the code at question itself.

Comment: @VTT all my code is included in a question. Tell me what to include more?

Comment: The project from GitHub works fine after disabling CLR support. So either it was a configuration problem with CLR getting accidentally enabled or neither the code in the question itself nor code from github are reproducing the stated problem.

Comment: @VTT thanks for pointing that. Unfortunately I can't remove the CLR support in an original project since it uses some types like `System::Guid`, `System::String`

Comment: You should remove them. If you need to interop with C# then you will need to extract code that uses CLR into separate binary.

Comment: @VTT That might work, thanks. But oh.. I'd hope to find another solution. And I still can't understand why it works with `/clr` under debug.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actualy the answer but the solution that I ended with.

Even though I'd prefer to get rid form `clr` support (as guys in a comments have suggested) - I couldn't use that as a solution for my original project. The original project contains a lot of managed types and replace all those usages will require a lot of working hours.

I started looking at another kind of a solution: removing the `#include <afxwin.h>` from `stdafx.h`. Eventually I found that replacing it with `#include <afx.h>` fixes the crash. And it still gives me the possibility to use manged types and MFC classes.

I don't have an explanation for this behavior but I hope this solution might help someone.